# Connecting monitor via HDMI is blank but windows still thinks it's attached

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

I have a Nvidia GeForce 1080 Ti and have always had 3 monitors connected to it via Display Port.

Today I got a VR headset. It HAS to be connected via Display port so I had to disconnect one of my monitors. I replaced the display port cable for that monitor with an HDMI cable. The graphics card now has 3 display port and 1 HDMI cable.

The monitor connected with an HDMI cable doesn't work. I've tried different inputs on the monitor and nothing. The monitor is connected according the windows and I can see it in the display properties dialog. It's just completely black.

How can I get the picture to be displayed on the third hdmi monitor as well as the 2 existing display port monitors?

Thanks

Comment: Check with the card manufacturer that it actually supports all 4 outputs simultaneously. Many don't, even if NVidia's chipset can. It may not have been built into the card. NVidia don't make graphics cards, btw, only graphics chipsets, so every card has different properties. It is very common for one DP & one HDMI to be shared.

Comment: I have a monitor that does not automatically switch inputs when they are changed, presumably this is some misguided power saving feature. Check your monitor manual to find out how to turn it on and change the inputs. For my Samsung monitor it involves pulling the rear 4-way (up/down/left/right) control switch downwards which triggers it to turn on and scan inputs.

Comment: @Mokubai - I'd made the assumption that the OP would have tried that, but good catch… you never know ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin given that this is the first monitor I've had in nearly 30 years that *didn't* automatically scan inputs I thought it is one of those things that might catch people off guard and need to be explicitly stated. I wish I had a way to actually get it to scan automatically...

Comment: Yeah, I had made sure it was on the correct input. Thanks

Comment: I have a Dell with an irritating quirk. if it's switched to my PC rather than Mac, if I reboot the PC it makes the Mac 'forget' it's attached & shuffles all windows to the other screen. If it's switched to the Mac, it's no issue.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I just needed to change the cable.